# How to prevent AndroidStudio from opening LogCat (tab) when pressing "Run"?

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I press "Run" project on Android Studio - LogCat tab is opening. This is annoying.

I was looking at Settings but couldn't find the answer.

Who knows how to stop it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Go to the run configurations (Run -> Edit Configurations) and select the run configuration you wish to edit. Select the Miscellaneous tab and uncheck the "Show logcat automatically" option.

Comment: Run->Edit Configurration->Miscellaneous->Show Logcat automatically

Comment: this works vice versa in case you want Logcat auto popup after Run in Giraffe